# Function modifies the string from the last call

Tags: c, string, function

```
void Consonanti(char s[],char v[3]) {
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; (i < strlen(s) && j < 3); i++)
    {
        if ( (s[i] != 'A') && (s[i] != 'E') && (s[i] != 'I') && (s[i] != 'O') && (s[i] != 'U'))
        {
            v[j] = s[i];
            j++;
        }
        
    }

    v[3] = '\0';
}


int main ()  {

    char CognomeConsonanti[3], NomeConsonanti[3];

    Consonanti(persona.cognome,CognomeConsonanti); 

    printf("%s ",CognomeConsonanti);

    Consonanti(persona.nome,NomeConsonanti); 
    
    printf("%s",NomeConsonanti);

    

    return 0;
}
```

Function "Consonanti" should put in v[], which is CognomeConsonanti and then NomeConsonanti in the second call, the first 3 consonants of the string s[]. It does and if printfs are like this it prints correctly, but if I put the first printf after the second call of Consonanti that the output is wrong and it looks like CognomeConsonanti is modified by the second call of Consonanti even tho I pass a different string. I can't understand why nor what could I do to fix it.

Comment: `3` is an interesting number.

Comment: Your strlen(s) isn't doing what you think it's doing because you have not init'd persona.cognome properly? Can't say for sure because your code isn't complete.

Comment: If an array is declared like `char CognomeConsonanti[3]` and passed to a function as `v` then `v[3] = '\0';` is accessing past the end of the array. The valid indices are 0 - 2. Allocate more space.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put the first three constants you need `char v[4]` instead of `char v[3]` and `char CognomeConsonanti[3], NomeConsonanti[3];` should also be `char CognomeConsonanti[4], NomeConsonanti[4];` The line `v[3] = '\0';` is going to stomp beyond the end of `v` otherwise.

You have to allocate room for the `\0`.